# Error 404: No target servlet configured for uri

Tags: websphere

I just got done with a new Web module built with Spring Framework. Till now I was testing all the pages on my local machine using Tomcat. Today after I moved the application to Websphere,
I am getting the following error:

```
      Error 404: No target servlet configured for uri
```

is there anything I need to do in web.xml or somewhere? I deployed an EAR file on my WAS , which has another war file.

Below is the output I am seeing on the console, if thats any help.

```
The resource WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xmi that is defined in URI WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xmi for module analytics.war is not valid.  The resource has a cross reference org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.webapplication.internal.impl.WebAppImpl@4be44be4 (eProxyURI: WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID) that cannot be resolved.
[6/17/09 15:24:49:465 CDT] 00000011 ArchiveDeploy W   ADMA0091E: The resource WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi that is defined in URI WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi for module analytics.war is not valid.  The resource has a cross reference org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.webapplication.internal.impl.WebAppImpl@7b7a7b7a (eProxyURI: WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID) that cannot be resolved.
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you haven't got your servlet configured correctly.  I'd say your web.xml has a servlet-name entry that doesn't correspond to a -servlet.xml file in your WEB-INF directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error for my json response. This is fixed by setting contentLength in the action.

Answer (score 0):

**ibm-web-bnd.xmi** has an attribute: `fileServingEnabled`.

This controls if `Websphere` is serving static content or not (index.html, pictures, etc.).

It is true, by default if omitted, but you can make sure it is on by adding it to tag `WebAppExtension`

```
fileServingEnabled="true"
```